# Simple Injector Usage with UseApplicationInsights/AddApplicationInsights in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, simple-injector

I am building an ASP.NET Core 2.1 app. For app insight telemetry I have my custom class but I also want to use built-in `ITelemetryInitializer`'s. Does Simple Injector automatically resolves these dependencies when Auto Cross wiring is enabled?

**UPDATE**

I tried below piece of code and got the error as shown below. I am not sure how else Auto Crosswiring is supposed to work.

```
container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle = new AsyncScopedLifestyle();

services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
services.AddSingleton<IControllerActivator>(
    new SimpleInjectorControllerActivator(container));

services.EnableSimpleInjectorCrossWiring(container);
services.UseSimpleInjectorAspNetRequestScoping(container); 

container.AutoCrossWireAspNetComponents(app);

services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(
    applicationInsightsLoggerConfig.InstrumentationKey);

var test = Container.GetInstance<TelemetryConfiguration>();
```

> The registered delegate for type TelemetryConfiguration threw an
>   exception. The registered delegate for type IServiceScope threw an
>   exception. The IServiceScope is registered as 'Async Scoped'
>   lifestyle, but the instance is requested outside the context of an
>   active (Async Scoped) scope.'

Thanks

Comment: Hi Steven, please the update in question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is caused by [a bug](https://github.com/simpleinjector/SimpleInjector/issues/581) in version 4.3.0 of the ASP.NET Core integration package for Simple Injector.

Due to the bug, any **auto** cross-wired dependency can *only* be resolved within the context of an active Scope, even if the dependency is a `Singleton`. `TelemetryConfiguration` is a `Singleton`.

When explicitly cross-wiring that dependency (i.e., using `container.CrossWire<TelemetryConfiguration>(app)`) the problem would go away, since `CrossWire` does allow `Singletons` to be resolved outside an active scope.

The problem has been resolved in [patch release 4.3.1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SimpleInjector.Integration.AspNetCore/4.3.1) of the integration package. In this version, you can resolve `TelemetryConfiguration` outside the context of an active web request or Simple Injector `Scope`.

In case the cross-wired service, however, is `Transient` or `Scoped`, you still need to either have an active web request, or, in case running on a background thread, an active Simple Injector `Scope`.